# Was 'offer' in "(...) that no way of reaching that place would offer, till (...)" used as an intransitive verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, intransitive-verbs

Is ***offer*** used as an intransitive verb in the following passage from [Moby-Dick?](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701)

> Much was I disappointed upon learning that the little packet for Nantucket had already sailed, and that no way of reaching that place ***would offer***, till the following Monday.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offer#Verb) suggests that ***offer*** is used here as an intransitive verb, meaning to happen, to present itself. What do y'all think?

Comment: That sounds pretty close to what the sentence suggests, although a closer approximation of the meaning might be _would be available_.

Comment: ' ... would present itself ....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Would offer* is an unusual construction in this context.

It's not really possible to tell if it's being used as a transitive or intransitive verb, because it depends on how you interpret its meaning.

---

### Transitive Interpretation

> No way of reaching that place <sup>(object)</sup> would *be offered* <sup>(transitive verb)</sup> [by someone] <sup>(missing subject).</sup>

In short, if *would offer* is the same as *would be offered*, then the phrase is a passive construction with the object coming before the transitive verb.

---

### Intransitive Interpretation

> No way of reaching that place <sup>(subject)</sup> would *appear* <sup>(intransitive verb).</sup>

In this case, what was the object of the clause in the transitive interpretation becomes the subject of the clause in the intransitive interpretation.

---

So, because of the odd use of *would offer*, its transitivity or intransitivity is ambiguous.